# Reset Timeout of the same timer in a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, settimeout, cleartimeout

I guess that this could be a duplicate because of the simple nature of the question, but I could not find any answer.

I am setting a Timeout function in a foor loop if a certain condition is true. As I don't want to declare the Timeout within the loop I wrote a setTimeout function to set it outside.
I want to use only one timer, which is reset, if it is already running, otherwise the timer should be set the first time.
My problem is, that the function sets multiple timers although I am using a clearTimeout().

My code:

```
    var timeout_id;
    var things = [true, true, false, true, true];

    var setTimer = function(timer_id, duration) {
        console.log("timer_id: ", timer_id);
        // clear timeout of the given Id
        clearTimeout(timer_id);
        timer_id = setTimeout(function() {
            // reset flag
            console.log("Timer timed out");
        }, duration);
        console.log("timer_id: ", timer_id);
    };

    for (var i = things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (things[i]) {
            setTimer(timeout_id, 900);
            console.log("Timer set because value of : " + i + " = ", things[i]);
        }
    }
```

What I get in the console is:

```
timer_id:  undefined
timer_id:  1
Timer set because value of : 4 =  true
timer_id:  undefined
timer_id:  2
Timer set because value of : 3 =  true
timer_id:  undefined
timer_id:  3
Timer set because value of : 1 =  true
timer_id:  undefined
timer_id:  4
Timer set because value of : 0 =  true
timer timed out
timer timed out
timer timed out
timer timed out
```

I don't understand why my timer_id is increased every time.

I am passing the id and reset the timer of it. After that I am setting a timer on the same Id, ain't I?
Is the reference to the var timeout_id not given and changes it from inside the setTimer function?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are passing 'timer_id' to the function and you are setting that to setTimeout(...)

Don't you want to use the variable 'timeout_id' of the outer scope instead?

Comment: I did not want that because I want to call the setTimer function on different timer variables. But check my answer. I think I got a solution there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your setTimer function to:

```
var timer_ids = {};

var setTimer = function(timer_id, duration) {
    console.log("timer_id: ", timer_id);
    // clear timeout of the given Id
    clearTimeout(timer_ids[timer_id]);
    timer_ids[timer_id]= setTimeout(function() {
        // reset flag
        console.log("Timer timed out");
    }, duration);
    console.log("timer_id: ", timer_id);
};
```

Comment: Well that would be my first approach as well, but because I want to have two timers at least (which should be running simultaneously) I definitely want to call the setTimer function two times with different Ids.

Lets say I have a timer resetting a timer after a click, and a timer after a hover. I need to different timers and I want to call
setTimer(first_timer_id);
and setTimer(sec_timer_id);
Both in a for loop, and that's why I want to reset each one if necessary...

Comment: Oh, so then you could put the timeout_id in a hashmap (json object)
where the key is your 'timer' id, and the value is the timeout_id - like so:

clearTimeout(timerIds[timerId]);
timerIds[timerId] = setTimeout()..:;

where timerIds is the variable outside of the setTimer function scope, i'll update my answer.

Comment: Cool. that's nice. I also had some context problems, because of my setTimer function is a private function of a separate «class». So _this_ was not the _this_ I expected and cause some trouble as well :).
Thanks anyway. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Question:**

> I don't understand why my timer_id is increased every time.
>
> I am passing the id and reset the timer of it. After that I am setting
> a timer on the same Id, ain't I?
>
> Is the reference to the var
> timeout_id not given and changes it from inside the setTimer function?

**Answer:**

The reason for to what is happening is that you are passing a `primitive` number type variable.

Primitive type variables are passed as value and not as a reference.

So in this line ...

```
setTimer(timeout_id, 900);
```

... the value of undefined is being passed every time ( not the reference to timeout_id )

and in this line ...

```
timer_id = setTimeout(function() {
```

... timer_id is not holding a reference to timeout_id as you are probably expecting.

So what is going on in your setTimer() function:

The first console.log outputs `undefined` because this is what is passed as parameter.

The second console.log outputs incremented id each time as this is what setTimeout() function returns with each call.

The reason why `setTimeOut()` returns an incremented unique integer id is that you can stick that id in a variable, so you can use this in future to clear that timeout with `clearTimeout( id )`

[Here is a nice explanation of 'Passing by Value or by Reference'](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Did not no that this was not passed as a reference. You never stop learning. Thanks

Comment: *did not know
(could not edit my comment to correct the typo...)

Comment: No problem It is good to know things like that to avoid similar problems in the future. Just added some more explanation to the anwser. I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution shortly after.
By returning the timeout_id and run the function on the timeout_id variable I get only one timer running:

```
    var timeout_id;
    var things = [true, true, false, true, true];

    var setTimer = function(timer_id, duration) {
        console.log("timer_id: ", timer_id);
        // clear timeout of the given Id
        clearTimeout(timer_id);
        timer_id = setTimeout(function() {
            // reset flag
            console.log("Timer timed out");
        }, duration);
        console.log("timer_id: ", timer_id);
        return timer_id;
    };

    for (var i = things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (things[i]) {
            timeout_id = setTimer(timeout_id, 900);
            console.log("Timer set because value of : " + i + " = ", things[i]);
        }
    }
```

Which logs out:

```
timer_id:  undefined
timer_id:  1
Timer set because value of : 4 =  true
timer_id:  1
timer_id:  2
Timer set because value of : 3 =  true
timer_id:  2
timer_id:  3
Timer set because value of : 1 =  true
timer_id:  3
timer_id:  4
Timer set because value of : 0 =  true
Timer timed out
```

You see. Only one timer is finishing after 900ms.